# Оптимизация обновления контролов (TImage)

Tags: delphi, оптимизация, delphi-xe, firemonkey

Я разрабатываю приложение под Android в XE7. Приложение работает с огромным числом изображений (Timage), которые нужно обновлять 30 раз в секунду. Мне нужно поддержание примерно 800 изображений на моем телефоне с FPS равным 30.

Ну так вот. Если речь идет о моем ноутбуке (2 ядра по 2.4ггц, мобильная видеокарта GT630m),  то хоть при 2500 юнитах FPS не опускается ниже 30, но на телефоне (Snapdragon 801, Adreno 330) уже при 500 юнитах FPS ~ 20.

Суть кода такая: есть процедура обновления позиций для изображений (отдельные переменные, не относятся к классу TImage), а в этих процедурах есть процедура обновления уже позиции самого изображения (то есть из переменных инфа присваивается уже полю TPosition из класса TImage). Там, где идет расчет позиций, всё очень быстро, но вот когда я хочу обновить поле TPosition класса TImage - медленно.

Подозрения такие: после каждого присваивания полю TPosition мое изображение начинает сразу обновляться. Можно ли как-нибудь сначала задать позиции TImage'ам, а потом их всех обновить после 500 итераций над всеми изображениями?

Да, я пробовал отдельно рисовать TBitMap, на котором рисую все свои изображения. Всё очень быстро до тех пор, пока я не продолжил (а мне нужно было) делать повороты этим изображениям: представьте, что нужно 500 изображений перевернуть, выстроить им верный масштаб и позицию? С позициями, кстати, все очень быстро, но с поворотами медленно (ОЧЕНЬ), TImage в этом случае наилучший вариант.

Да, я использовал GlobalUseGPUCanvas (далее GUGC). Тут немного странновато. Когда я присваиваю GUGC значение true на ноутбуке, то всё очень быстро, а когда false - медленно. Это верно, так и должно быть. Но когда на телефоне я присваиваю GUGC значение false, то при 500 юнитах FPS ~ 20, а когда GUGC = true, то FPS ~ 20. Разницы нет, что с аппаратным ускорением, что без. Что делать? Необходимо очень.

Comment: Двойная буферизация это был в правильную сторону шаг. Ну и на второй вопрос вы сами ответили, если узкое место в повороте, перепишите функции поворота и масштабирования сами, оптимизмруйте по скорости. Хотя моё мнение, что для телефона у вас завышенные требования, может есть смысл в корне поменять логику

Comment: @Isaev GlobalUseGPUCanvas - стандартная фича в FireMonkey, включающая аппаратное ускорение. На компе оно работает, и разница видна, а на телефоне - нет. Функции масштабирования и поворота тоже стандартные (FireMonkey). Я не знаю, как можно оптимизировать. Может, есть какие-нибудь свойства по типу "Обновлять только тогда, когда есть команда обновиться в родительском объекте"?

Comment: у TImage? Visible:=False; ...выполняем операции... Visible:=True; 
Пока он не видимый обновляться не будет по идее

Comment: @Isaev а мерцать не будет? + обновить всех за раз я не смогу, то есть процесс на форме будет такой: [Повторять] свойство Visible = true >> обновляем bitmap изображения >> Image рисуется на канве >> обновляем канву и выводим изображение [до тех пор, пока не будут обработаны 500 изображений]. 

А мне нужно так: [повторять] Обновляем bitmap изображения>> Image рисуется на канве >> [до тех пор, пока не будут обработаны 500 изображений] >> обновить канву и вывести.

Comment: У `TImage.Canvas` есть методы `Lock` и `UnLock`. Изображение не будет обновляться на экране, пока канвас залочен.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci у меня нет такого. Есть только TImage.Lock, но ничего не происходит

Comment: Рисуйте все объекты самостоятельно на одном Canvas.

Comment: @Человек_Борща я пробовал, все хорошо до тех пор, пока не поворачиваю объекты (TBitmap.Rotate) :C

Answer (score 2):

Забавная попытка продолжать забивать гвозди микроскопом. Canvas, TBitMap - это средство вывода информации, не для манипуляции оно.
Пишите свой рендер контента, на основе canvas или ещё как-то, где все манипуляции проходят в памяти, а не на canvas.

TImage совсем для подобного не подходит.
Каждое изображение перерисовывается самостоятельно, независимо от всех. В массовом масштабе это создает очень сильное проседание FPS.

И да, если в вашем мобильнике нет графического процессора (GPU), то GlobalUseGPUCanvas работать не будет.